# Получить актуальную ссылку на видео instagram

Tags: php, instagram

Есть ссылка непосредственно на сам видео ролик: [сслылка](https://instagram.fiev1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/48948082_213754342757540_3622810728402984285_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjY0MC5mZWVkLmRlZmF1bHQiLCJxZV9ncm91cHMiOiJbXCJpZ193ZWJfZGVsaXZlcnlfdnRzX290ZlwiXSJ9&_nc_ht=instagram.fiev1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=QeZ7KWhYGjAAX81rs-o&vs=17848641964315420_466201184&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdITGo2Z0trVkt1UGFNSUFBRjBkNzdvcHowWXlia1lMQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHRGpSNHdJbjdMSWRVd0lDQUVrTDI0RG5zVEFHYmtZTEFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwGIB3VzZV9vaWwBMBUAABgAFpT9x%2Fbc9vc)

Но она имеет срок действия.

Так же имеется **shortcode** поста с этим видео [ссылка на пост](https://www.instagram.com/p/BrfWJHXFgnQ/)

И еще имеется **id** поста: 1936363748194650576

Каким образом можно обновить ссылку непосредственно на само видео?

например, для обновления ссылки непосредственно на фото, нужно к ссылке на пост добавить **media/?size=m** и таким образом я могу всегда иметь актуальную ссылку на картинку https://www.instagram.com/p/BrfWJHXFgnQ/media/?size=m

А мне нужно непосредственно на видео.

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На входе имеется ссылка на пост: https://www.instagram.com/p/BrfWJHXFgnQ

На выходе должны получить ссылку на видеофайл.

---

Первым делом рекомендую установить [какой-нибудь плагин для браузера для просмотра JSON](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/jsonview?_category=extensions).

Итак, в Instagram есть мощная, но малоизвестная фишка: нужно добавить к адресу `?__a=1` и сервер нам покажет JSON-вариант вместо HTML. Это работает и для постов, и для аккаунтов.

Итак, переходим по ссылке `https://www.instagram.com/p/BrfWJHXFgnQ/?__a=1`. Потратив минуту на исследование документа, можно найти ссылку на видео по пути `graphql > shortcode_media > video_url`.

На PHP это буде выглядить как-то так:

```
<?php
$shortCode = "BrfWJHXFgnQ";
$endpoint = "https://www.instagram.com/p/{$shortCode}/?__a=1";
$response = file_get_contents($endpoint);
$responseJSON = json_decode($response);
$videoUrl = $responseJSON->graphql->shortcode_media->video_url;

echo $videoUrl;
```